# how to use variable in python os.path.exists

Tags: python, linux

Here is my code

```
[root@04 ~]# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May  5 2011, 16:39:10)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> pid = open('/var/run/httpd.pid' , 'r').read()
>>> print pid
24154
>>> os.path.exists('/proc/',pid)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: exists() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Even i tried following, its not working. How do i use variable `pid` in `os.path.exists` command?

```
>>> os.path.exists('/proc/'+pid)
False
>>>
```

**EDIT :**

if i type manually PID number it works

```
>>> print pid
24154

>>> os.path.exists('/proc/24154')
True
>>>
```

Comment: Opening files is best done using the `with` statement, that way, the file will be closed correctly in all situations.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking there. Do you mean [the syntax for the with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)?

Comment: I meant how to use *with* statement with open file?

Comment: Instead of `print pid`, just type `pid` and press enter, and the problem will become apparent. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Satish I linked to an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `http.pid` doesn't contain just the number, but also a newline character. Since Python's `read`, unlike shell's backquotes, doesn't strip trailing newlines, the `pid` variable contains a string like `"12345\n"` and your code is testing whether `"/proc/12345\n"` exists.

To correct the problem, call [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) on the string you've read from the file:

```
os.path.exists(os.path.join('/proc', pid.strip()))
```

Comment: +1, This just clicked for me, but you got in there first. This is the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: awesome it works!! >>> os.path.exists(os.path.join('/proc', pid.strip()))
True

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) here:

```
os.path.exists(os.path.join('/proc/', pid))
```

Note, however, that your concatenation should have worked (albeit, it is more fragile and not recommended, compared to `os.path.join()`), so are you sure the path does exist? `False` implies it worked and the path does not exist.

[The docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) note:

> Return True if path refers to an existing path or an open file
>   descriptor. Returns False for broken symbolic links. On some
>   platforms, **this function may return False if permission is not granted
>   to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path
>   physically exists.**

Emphasis added. This implies you may have a permission issues, if the path does exist.

Comment: Ran a few quick tests. Concatenation works but @satish (and everyone else) should avoid if possible

Comment: @Satish How doesn't it work? Does it return `False`? If so, have you checked the file exists, and your script has permission to execute `os.stat()` on it?

Comment: if i type PID number manually (like i did in my question) it works but not with variable.